# visual studio 2012 ultimate incompatible

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, incompatibletypeerror

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and then i Install Entity Framework using package manager console now when i open my project class library loaded successfully but my mvc web project not load
It gives me the error

> incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your WebProject MVC 1 or 2? If yes, then according to [this article](http://www.jhovgaard.com/visual-studio-2012-web-project-is-incompatible/) you should run [an upgrade to MVC3](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008).

If it is not, then [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/opening-an-asp-net-mvc-project-without-having-asp-net-mvc-installed-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation) mentions another way to open this project.

Comment: Thank you Gerino the link you provided in second worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can mark the answer as a selected answer then :)